# Contact form 7 select box different value-text than content-text in option

Tags: plugins, forms, options, plugin-contact-form-7, select

Does anyone know how I can set a different value in the select options in the Contact Form 7 plugin? Here is an example of the HTML I'd like it to generate:

```
<select>
    <option value="1">My car</option>
    <option value="2">Your car</option>
</select>
```

Comment: If no native solution exists, you can solve this with jQuery `val()`, `show()` and `hide()`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It looks like this is supported by Contact Form 7 natively, it's just not very obvious on how to make it happen.

Here's a documentation page explaining the functionality: http://contactform7.com/selectable-recipient-with-pipes/

Basically, all you have to do is put the values like so:

```
"Visible Value|actual-form-value"
```

What comes before the pipe `|` character will be shown in the form, and what comes after will be the actual value filled in for the form.

Hope that helps!

Comment: This does not work.  There documentation is incorrect.

Comment: @SolomonClosson Actually this still works; it's just funky.  The form HTML doesn't show the 'raw' value, but as the link states at the end you can access them with the prefix `_raw_`, e.g. `_raw_YOURFIELD` rather than `YOURFIELD`.

Comment: This will work server side only. According to the documentation this is to prevent values to be sent to the browser client, so if you want to access the option value with javascript (jQuery's val()) instead of the option text (jQuery's text()), then go with Demilio's solution.

Comment: how to do that if im using the "data" attribute to populate the select ?

Comment: For an example implementation have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52856416/11211100).

Comment: This works, but not in the way in which the original poster was expecting. The original poster expects a solution in which the `<select>` element in the browser contains both the visible text and the hidden value, and when the form is submitted the hidden value would be sent to the server. The way that CF7 actually works when you use the pipe character is that it only builds the visible value into the `<select>` element, but when the visible text is submitted with the form, CF7 then **replaces that with the hidden value** before generating the email or saving the entry.

Answer (score 4):

I solved this by publishing the standard contct form 7 form first, then I copied the source code created from all the short-codes from contact form 7. Then insteaed of using the shortcode as the select tag I used a real select-tag with  in it. This way I could use the contact form 7 engine and at the same time set my own value-text in the option tags...

Comment: Won't that prevent you from using the values in the email? If you create a checkbox in HTML with name="mybox", I don't think putting [mybox] in the email will work, will it?